# two item does not align next to each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i am trying to my page responsive but when i inspect and look into mobile view they do align next to each on desktop that was fine but on mobile view it look like that[image]

i wnat shopping carticon and button next to eachother so my navbar does not llok stretch
her is my code

```
    <!-- navbar -->
<!-- Image and text -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #025;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{% url 'accounts:home' %}" style="font-size: 25px; font-weight:600;">
      <img src="{% static 'image/logo/logo.png' %}" class="d-inline-block align-text-center logo-img"
        style="margin-left: 150px; height: 40px;">
      BuyBuy
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-nav dekstop_search">
      <form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'products:search' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" name="search" required>
        <button class="btn sea btn-outline-primary" type="submit" value="Search"><i class="fas fa-search text-white"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>

<!-- Links -->
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

  <!-- Right -->
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
      <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{wish|length}}</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{wish|length}}</a>
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'orders:cart' %}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{request.session.cart.keys|length}}</span></a>
      <div class="dropdown">
      <img class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="height:50px; border-radius: 50%; margin-right:150px;"
        src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}">
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li class="item text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;"> Hi <strong
            style="color: #B9C04C; cursor:default;"> {{ user.username }}  </strong></li>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'accounts:profile'  request.user.username %}">My Account</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'orders:myorders' %}">My Order</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">My Address</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">My Cart</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Log Out</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Settings</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Help</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'orders:cart' %}"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; color:#025; padding:3px;">{{request.session.cart.keys|length}}</span></a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary text-white">Log In</button></a>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

any help will be appreciate i trie like display inline-block but doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Can you please give the full code of navbar?

Comment: @Mahadi added full navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent `<div>`, like:

```
<div class="navbar-nav" style="display:flex">
```

Comment: didn't work still same

Comment: @Blackranger if you also add `flex-direction: row;` , does it work?

Comment: @Blackranger no problem :) Glad it worked.

Comment: @Blackranger On which element you applied `display: flex` ?

Comment: on navbar-nav your please update your ans acc to gosi first display flex then flex direction row

Comment: @AvinashChandra please update your answer with the added code you suggested to Gosi

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so your problem is solved. That's great.

Looks like you are using Bootstrap-5, your code was having problem cause you were using lots of inline styles, not closing tag(s), Not using proper navigation menu structures. These were conflicting with Bootstrap.

You should always code by Bootstraps guidelines, otherwise your code won't work as you desire.

Now let me give you some suggestion to improve and optimize your code.

**1. Try to avoid inline styles. Use Bootstrap classes to style your html elements.**

```
**Example:**

    <span class="badge" style="background-color: white; padding:3px;">
        ....
    </span>

Change it to:

    <span class="badge bg-white p-1">
        ....
    </span>

Read: Bootstrap [Background Color][1], [Spacing][2], [Colors][3]
```

**2. Use bootstrap's structure to organize your navigation links**

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                <span class="badge bg-white text-primary p-1">{{wish|length}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white text-center">
                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                <span class="badge bg-white text-primary p-1">{{wish|length}}</span>
            </a>      
        </li>
    </ul>
Read: [Bootstrap Navbar][4]
```

**3. Make sure you close every tags. (In your code some tags are not
closed.)**

Comment: Appreciate that thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use flexbox which is provided in css.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.className { display: flex; }` property

Comment: still same nothing happen